# PDF editor, creator alternatives?

Tags: pdf, software-rec, adobe-acrobat

Anyone have any thoughts on the following solutions for PDF alternatives to Acrobat?:

**Nuance PDF Converter 6 Professional** & **BlueBeam PDF Revu 7 Standard**

Nuance is cheaper and seems to have all the same features, however I have not used either of them and wanted to get your experiences or thoughts on either if you have any.

Any other recommended solutions? We are looking for an alternative to acrobat within our network.

Comment: What are your requirements for PDF creation?

Comment: PDF creating and plugin for Office etc and markup/editing features.

Comment: I've found that for my PDF creation needs I can use PDFCreator.  It may not be what you want since it isn't a PDF editor.  I would print/convert to PDF so I didn't have to worry about whether the recipient had the appropriate Office version to view my document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you already have Microsoft Office 2007, there is a download that gives you the option to save directly to PDF:

[2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041)

Comment: Some of our user's are on 2007 some are not, though nice link, I didn't know about it. I think we'll probably go with Nuance's solution for editing/markups. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I use [OpenOffice](http://openoffice.org) to export documents to PDF - quick, easy, and free.

Answer (score 3):

There's a PDFCreator project - on SourceForge, I think - that you can download and install. It registers as a printer, so when you are in any program that has a print function, you can choose to print to PDF. Very useful, and dead simple.

EDIT: it's not for editing PDFs, just for converting from existing documents/pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever used the free PDF Reader, myself, but have you looked at [Foxit PDF Creator](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/creator/) and [Foxit PDF Editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/editor/)?

Comment: I have looked at Foxit and it was actually one I've considered, I'll keep it in mind if these two solutions fall out of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I like [pdfFactory](http://fineprint.com/pdf/) from FinePrint Software.  It installs as a virtual printer and lets you save the result as a PDF.  It's easy to use, and not incredibly expensive.  My needs were not complex.  If yours aren't either, I suggest you check it out – there's a free trial.

[image: pdfFactory virtual printer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think a really good one is Foxit Phantom, found here: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/PDF_Editor/

It's got all the functionality of Acrobat, but it's easier to use, less expensive and pretty much an industry standard these days.

Give it a shot! I hope it works for you.